# IE6 user browse Sharepoint 2013 get the same Javascript error on everypage

Tags: javascript, ie6

I understand IE6 is no longer support in SP2010 and SP2013. My only requirement is hiding the Javascript error and let the user able to read the Sharepoint page only.

In my test environment, IE6 user can browse and use some function (like upload and download files) without issue. The only problem is Javascript error (yellow ! at left bottom corner) complaining row 2 char 84618 "object doesn't support this property or method".

I have tested in custom Master pages and default oslo pages. Every page return the same error so I think it is the JavaScript in Ribbon bar causing the warning. I have hided the bar with CSS already. Just not sure how to hide the JS from IE6 user and I don't know which line of code causing it.

I understand it is a unsupported situation. Any input is helful and thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be an uphill battle to get SharePoint 2013 to function properly with IE6. A majority of the core JavaScript code is not compatible with IE6, and I don't think there is any way around it.

Answer (score 1):

That's so dirty, I like it. I'll give you the outline of the solution:

The Sharepointy way:

- Deploy a DelegatePageHead module with an UserControl
- Detect an IE6 request on the server side
- Change the masterpage to the olso_IE6.master that won't have the ribbon and other scripts creating issues.

If you have a custom master it can have its own codebehind and you can wrap the ribbon with a placeholder, and hide it on IE6 so you don't need a second masterpage for IE6.

The bruteforce way:

- In the beginning of your `<head>` for your master, add:

  ```
  <!--[if IE 6]>
  <script>
    <!--
     function onErrorResumeNext() { return true; }
     window.onerror=onErrorResumeNext;
    //-->
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the "faulting" javascript file for IE6 users without using a custom mastepage. If you have the IIS URL rewrite mode installed on your WFE servers you can create a rule that will detect IE6 only using the browser agent in the conditions and "rewrite" the request to a modified (or empty) version. This has to be done on any WFE in the farm serving content to end users. Maybe only on web apps that need this fix.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

The other possible way is to develop an HTTP module and the same in code. Get into every request (maybe just the JS files) and analyse the client (IE6). If the unsupported client is requesting the javascript you could deliver a custom crafted "working" for IE6. As a starting point check out this codeplex solution:

http://blockspdhttpmodule.codeplex.com/

Beware of any performance impact running custome code on all of your requests!

Did you check if the build in mobile feature are a possible solution?
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161351(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161351%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Maybe if you configure the compat.browser file to identify IE6 as mobile this will work.
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393836%28v=office.15%29.aspx)